# Getting rid of blank page after figure and naming figures

Tags: graphics, floats

The following is my code:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\title{}
\author{}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[update,prepend]{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{eulervm}
%\usepackage{iwona}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\raggedbottom

\everymath{\displaystyle} 

\newcommand{\pder}[2][]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}

\renewcommand\textfraction{.1}

\begin{document}


\newpage
\section{Figures}



\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{Bootstrapped Probability of Default for Banks} \\  \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont This graph plots the mean and median bootstrapped probabilities of default ($PoD$) of 28 Euro Area (EA) banks. The banks used can be found in Table~\ref{tab:bankabbreviation}. All reported $PoD$s are annualized 5-year cumulative CDS-derived $PoD$s. All CDS contracts are Euro denominated. Period: 01/01/2008 to 28/02/2013.}
  \label{bootstrapbank}

\vspace{1 cm}

\caption{Panel A}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{1.pdf}

\vspace{2 cm}

\caption{Panel B}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{2.pdf}

\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{apa-good}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

---

The output is this:

[image]

[image]

I have two problems:

1) For some reason, the above code produces a blank page with title **A Figures** and then produces the figures on the next page, how do I make the figure start straight after the title **A Figures**?

2) For my figure how do I get rid of Figure 2 and Figure 3 next to the Panel A and Panel B? I would like to just name both graphs "Panel A" and "Panel B"

Thanks!

Comment: Because you have put it all into one figure, it does not fit on the page with the heading, it os more common to use a figure environment for each, however if you use `begin{figure}[!htp]` it might fit (I can't test without the images) don't use `\caption` and just use `Panel A`

Comment: @David Carlisle Perfect! Fixed both of my problems, thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have put it all into one `figure`, it does not fit on the page with the heading.

It is more common to use a `figure` environment for each, however if you use

```
\begin{figure}[!htp]
```

it might fit (I can't test without the images).

To split up the images without introducing new numbers, don't use `\caption` and just use `Panel A`